# Where did the 'World/Surface/Strength' setting go in 2.8?

Tags: world

When I go to:
World/Surface/
the Strength setting (available in 2.79b) does not exist. Google was not helpful in trying to find where this setting has gone.

Comment: So it appears when i set the HDRI, 2.8 doesn't add a 'Background' node which has the Strength control. I never had to add this manually in 2.79b... Oh well, problem solved! Thanks to Duarte Farrajota Ramos for tipping me off on what was missing!

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere at all, they are exactly where they were before.

Off course you can only see them if *Use Nodes* is enabled, otherwise those settings are unavailable.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't exist for me
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aNNuBoExrEK8hTzpHEh3bnk-VfNqA-ij